# How to construct the lambda expression when implementing HiddenForEach with MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement a HTML-Helper method for ASP.NET MVC5 similar to `Html.HiddenFor` but I would like to pass it an `IList<T>` and have it call `Html.HiddenFor` for each of them.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
public static void HiddenForEach<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, IList<TProperty>>> expression)
{
    IList<TProperty> allItems = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
    for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Count; ++i)
    {
        var withIndex = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProperty>>(...??...);
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(htmlHelper.HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(withIndex).ToHtmlString());
    }
}
```

I am invoking the expression to get the `IList` and then, I am iterating over all items in it.

However, I don't know how to buid the expression to access one specific element in the `IList`, i.e. how to build the expression to get something equivalent to `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListOfSomething[0])`, `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListOfSomething[1])`, etc.

Furthermore, I am not sure if I should use `htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer` to output the generated HTML or rather concatenate the `MvcHtmlString`s somehow and return them?

Comment: If you go digging up in the source code you can see how they did it for `HiddenFor` and get an idea of what you want to do. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs

Comment: Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40106334/387023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start by stating that I'm not going to answer your question completely, but the progress I've made might help another to solve it.

In essence, I'm trying to transform the expression from something like `x => x.People` to `x => x.People[0]` before calling `htmlHelper.HiddenFor();`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Count; ++i)
{
  PropertyInfo indexProperty = typeof(IList<TProperty>).GetProperty("Item");

  IndexExpression indexExpression = Expression.MakeIndex(
    expression.Body, 
    indexProperty, 
    new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(i) }
  );

  Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> lambda = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProperty>>(
      indexExpression,
      expression.Parameters[0]
  );

  MvcHtmlString hidden = htmlHelper.HiddenFor(lambda);
}
```

To summarise, I'm pretty close. The only problem is that the expression is translated to `x => x.People.Items[0]` and calling `htmlHelper.HiddenFor(lambda)` results in an error that I can't get around.

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions

I'll investigate a little more and see what I can come up with.

Comment: The trick is to not use the index expression but instead the `"get_Item"` method and use that to create the lambda expression. I will post  the solution in a separate answer but accept yours since you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @j00hi Ah, that makes sense, and well found.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working solution, developed based on Matt Griffiths suggestion:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForEach<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, IList<TProperty>>> expression)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    IList<TProperty> allItems = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
    for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Count; ++i)
    {
        var getListItemExpr = Expression.Call(
            expression.Body, 
            typeof(IList<TProperty>).GetMethod("get_Item"), 
            Expression.Constant(i)
        );

        var lambdaWithIndex = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProperty>>( 
            getListItemExpr,  
            expression.Parameters
        );

        sb.Append(htmlHelper.HiddenFor(lambdaWithIndex).ToHtmlString());
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString())
}
```